# Grep to match patterns of an external file

Tags: file, design-patterns, grep, external

I am looking for something like unix grep, that can get the paterns from an external file.

I have a list of patterns on an file patterns.txt like this (but with much more entries):

```
234523.34
623253.45
3466.55
```

There is another file called to_search_on.txt and I need to keep only the lines that match patterns.txt.
This is to_search_on.txt file (but with more entries to):

```
kaosar,23443.44,0
ratro,2423545,0
pencod,3466.55,1
```

How can I do this?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `-f` option to read patterns from file

```
$ grep -f patterns.txt to_search_on.txt
pencod,3466.55,1
```

For more info `man grep` would give you as

```
  -f FILE, --file=FILE
              Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
```

Comment: It may be ok in this simple input, but what if line has more number.  `grep` will just search the whole line for pattern match, not just the second field.

Comment: @Jotne Yeah its a draw back of using grep, but it may work if the file is formated as in the example. But your answer is more specific +1 :)

Comment: @user3851412 Glad to hear it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk`

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$0]++;next} ($2 in a)' patterns.txt to_search_on.txt
pencod,3466.55,1
```

This will only give hit if pattern is found in second field (divided by `,`) 
It store the `patterns.txt` file in array `a`, then test it against `to_search_on.txt`